# IntelliJ Split Window Navigation

Tags: intellij-idea

If I split the editor window (horizontal or vertical) into N tab groups, how do I switch/toggle from one tab group to another via the keyboard?  If all of the tabs are in the same group you can switch from each tab easily (CTRL + right/left arrow), but when they're in separate tab groups I can't.  I've searched through the key mappings and have not found one that seems to accomplish this.  I know I can use the mouse, but I'm trying to find ways to avoid the mouse and stay with the keyboard.

TIA for any help on this.

Comment: **[IntelliJ IDEA advanced tips and tricks: Multiple Editors](https://youtu.be/pM66JbggAjU?list=PL2Nd9fpteKnV7lDBOl1bYc4sdhR3bu90i)**

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Ctrl+Tab** and **Ctrl+Shift+Tab** for Window | **Goto Next Splitter** and **Goto Previous Splitter**. However, these hotkeys may be taken by the **Switcher**, so you need to remap them in **Settings | Keymap**.

Comment: Ha! thank you, that pointed me in the right direction.  I deleted the **Switcher** mapping and it now works to Ctrl+Tab between the groups.  That default mapping was interfering with both of those **Goto** mappings.

Comment: Goto next splitter does not work.  Intellij version 13.1.4  Remapping does not help: the window title changes but the CURSOR does not move to the other splitter

Comment: +12.  I have been wondering about this for ages... one less mouse-bound operation for IntelliJ & Co.

Comment: Great, thanks. Since I use VIM plugin, I remapped the navigation to CTRL+PgUp and CTRL+PgDown and use VIM commands (G, gg) to move across the editor.

Answer (score 101):

It looks like it's now mapped to **Alt+Tab** and **Shift+Alt+Tab** so no need to remap (at least for OSX 10.5+ settings).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same case and this plugin solve my problem:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7475-tab-shifter
- https://github.com/dkandalov/tab-shifter

As I write this, here is what it support:

- Move tab to another editor split
- Move focus between splits
- Resize the split

You may refer more details on the page/github. It works pretty well in 2019.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can switch the splitters with `CTRL+E` and then `ENTER`.

[image: example]

If you have more then 2 splits, then you can navigate or quick search in the *Recent Files* dialog.

Switching the splitters with the Switcher doesn't work.